# Awk string help finding information

Tags: string, awk, output, gsub

Hi I have a line I am trying to parse. The line looks like this

> Edward C. Anderson, Broker ~ 813.841.2773 ~ ed@action100realty.com

I am new to awk and have tried to do my research. I see that you can use sub() and gsub to do this. I  am trying to put these three pieces of information into my output of name phone and email. I was thinking I could use a regular expression to grab stuff from before the ~ and between and end but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan ol' bash:

```
echo "Edward C. Anderson, Broker ~ 813.841.2773 ~ ed@action100realty.com" | 
while IFS='~' read -r name phone email; do 
    echo "name is $name, phone is $phone and email is $email" 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-F` switch of `awk`, ex. to get the name (first position):

```
echo "Edward C. Anderson, Broker ~ 813.841.2773 ~ ed@action100realty.com" |
    awk -F'~' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Thank you. I am running my file through the script though. Is it the same method?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Edward C. Anderson, Broker ~ 813.841.2773 ~ ed@action100realty.com" | awk -F'[~,]' '{print $1,$3,$4}'

Edward C. Anderson  813.841.2773   ed@action100realty.com
```